# CNFT Lock/Freeze possible?

Tags: rust, metaplex, nft, cnft, freeze

It is possible to freeze/freezeDelegated for metaplex NFTs. Also pNFTs can be locked in user wallet. I am not able to find any such feature for cNFT, is it possible to freeze/lock cNFT in user wallet?